# I cant see the windows taskbar in Minecraft fullscreen

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have always been able to see the taskbar while in Minecraft full screen and have been able to easily change to the browser from the game and back again. I accidentally pressed something and now the taskbar is gone. I can still use the windows key to get to the browser, but it makes the computer really slow for some reason. I want to be able to have Minecraft take up the full screen, but still be able to see the taskbar at the bottom.

Here is a visual: [image: minecraft screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure you didn't use maximized windowed mode? Fullscreen usually tends to take 100% of your screen, hides the taskbar and everything. Hit <kbd>F11</kbd>, Then the maximize button on top right of the window.

Comment: I beleive that this is more of a suggestion worthy to be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @CaolanMC I disagree.  This is typically how full screen works in most applications.    Based off what the OP said _I accidentally pressed something_, this is likely what happened (I know I've accidentally hit F11 to go full screen before).  To add, I believe there is also an option in Minecraft to play either windowed or full screen.

Comment: @TimmyJim I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

You probably hit <kbd>F11</kbd> by accident as that is Minecraft's shortcut for full screen mode. In proper full screen mode you're not supposed to be able to see your taskbar. You were probably using it as a maximized window beforehand. To fix this all you must do is hit <kbd>F11</kbd> again (or turn off full screen in game settings) and make the window maximized by pressing the square in the top right corner of the minecraft window.